# how to tell in gdb if a std::string has been destructed

Tags: gdb

I am debugging a core dump and it seems my app has cored when making a copy of a std::string. The contents of the sting look a little corrupted, so the crash is either due to the string having been destructed before the copy, or because some other code has overwritten part of the string. Is it possible in gdb to tell if the string still exists (and therefore has had its memory overwritten) or if the string has been destructed previous to the copy?

Comment: Is it possible for you to run again your program under `valgrind` if you are on Linux?

Comment: debuggers are not some kind of mirracle-workers. Destructor is just a function, and debugger can't tell you if it ever was called for your specific 'this', so if destructor itself haven't marked anything as deleted - you can't ensure that it wasn't called (at least not by core dump - of course runtime conditional breakpoint could help you, if you can reproduce a bug)

Answer (score 2):

If you use gcc and std::string from gcc (and not from STLport for example) then there is an internal structure inside std::string that holds _M_refcount which is below zero after destruction (Here is in russian a detailed explanation with some figures ["Несколько подробностей об std::string"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/175691/):

This is from basic_string.h from gcc 4.3.3:

```
        void
        _M_dispose(const _Alloc& __a)
        {
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING
          if (__builtin_expect(this != &_S_empty_rep(), false))
#endif
            if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&this->_M_refcount,
                                                       -1) <= 0)
              _M_destroy(__a);
        }  // XXX MT

      ~basic_string()
      { _M_rep()->_M_dispose(this->get_allocator()); }
```

So this is a simple test:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  {
    std::string s1("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUF1234567890");
    printf("Before destruction\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and built:

> g++ -m64 -g -pthread main.cpp

And this is under gdb:

```
>gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x400787: file main.cpp, line 7.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:7
7           std::string s1("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUF1234567890");
(gdb) n
8           printf("Before destruction\n");
(gdb)  x/4gx (((void**)&s1)[0]-24)
0x601010:       0x000000000000001f      0x000000000000001f
0x601020:       0x0000000000000000      0x4847464544434241
(gdb)  x/32c (((void**)&s1)[0])
0x601028:       65 'A'  66 'B'  67 'C'  68 'D'  69 'E'  70 'F'  71 'G'  72 'H'
0x601030:       73 'I'  74 'J'  75 'K'  76 'L'  77 'M'  78 'N'  79 'O'  80 'P'
0x601038:       82 'R'  83 'S'  84 'T'  85 'U'  70 'F'  49 '1'  50 '2'  51 '3'
0x601040:       52 '4'  53 '5'  54 '6'  55 '7'  56 '8'  57 '9'  48 '0'  0 '\000'
(gdb) n
Before destruction
10        return 0;
(gdb)  x/4gx (((void**)&s1)[0]-24)
0x601010:       0x0000000000000000      0x000000000000001f
0x601020:       0x00000000ffffffff      0x4847464544434241
(gdb)  x/32c (((void**)&s1)[0])
0x601028:       65 'A'  66 'B'  67 'C'  68 'D'  69 'E'  70 'F'  71 'G'  72 'H'
0x601030:       73 'I'  74 'J'  75 'K'  76 'L'  77 'M'  78 'N'  79 'O'  80 'P'
0x601038:       82 'R'  83 'S'  84 'T'  85 'U'  70 'F'  49 '1'  50 '2'  51 '3'
0x601040:       52 '4'  53 '5'  54 '6'  55 '7'  56 '8'  57 '9'  48 '0'  0 '\000'
```

As you can see after destruction the value at 0x601020 becomes 0x00000000ffffffff. _M_refcount is four bytes long so it is ffffffff (-1) after destruction.

Comment: Nice one, but if string (char array) is actually already overwritten - it doesn't seem too reasonable to hope that refcount isn't. Regardless of it's value, it just doesn't confirming anything, does it?

Comment: Besides refcount there are other fields and dan can check them (_M_length and _M_capacity and _M_p). Of course it does not prove that overwriting had not happened. However my answer was mainly about destruction of the std::string. And I also recommended to run the program again under `valgrind`.

Comment: by no mean i'm not against your answer. It's great and precise, it just cannot be fully trusted (i mean not answer itself but the refcount, ofc.). However, even if bug cannot be reproduced, `valgrind`'s memcheck could reveal some obvious errors and potentially find exact problem, even if for some reasons it isn't noticable yet. As i've said before, i see no way to say 100% sure that destructor was ever called by crash dump alone, mainly because it's really hard to look at past events if there is no log.